# Rear Lights for Aero Seat post?

Tags: seatpost, taillight

I went to the Bike store looking for rear lights for my Aero seat post and for the life of me I couldn't find that fit. Its very skinny in the back and so the regular tail lights do not fit.

How would I search for something like this on amazon or elsewhere?

[image]

Comment: Did you try any search terms before posting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I search for something like this on amazon or elsewhere?

```
rear light aero seatpost
```

This works on Amazon and elsewhere.

Comment: Question is offtopic, should be on HowDoesSearchWork.stackexchange.com ???

Comment: @Mσᶎ This is answer.   Then vote to close the question and comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are other options than mounting the light on the seat post. There are lights that mount to the seat rails. There are also lights that will mount to the  seat stays. That may not be high enough for you, but it's another option.

Comment: Pretty sure that bike also has aero seat stays

Answer (score 0):

Remember there's nothing wrong with multiple lights.  If one stops when riding you generally don't notice until the ride's over.

- One on your helmet
- A rubber-band style one on the seat post
- A seat-rail mount light
- A seat stay light would be perfectly reasonable triple of light.

Do also have red rear reflectors.  My roadbike is red painted, and has red reflective tape that is hard to see separately, but at night time it reflects nicely.  Reflectors are legally mandated in many places too.

Comment: wow that is a lot of lights to charge. I am already annoyed with usb charging

Comment: @nolawipetros Agreed - USB charging means the unit costs more, and its possibly more vulnerable to rain ingress.  I use big 18650 batteries on some things, they last 3-4 months.  The main headlight uses 4 of them and I charge that once a week in winter because it gives no warning when low.  The flashies run for 1-6 months on a pair of CR2032 watch batteries.... I buy three trays of 20 of these from dx.com for around $5 per tray, so each battery is 20c.  Downside, its not the most ecologically responsible power source.

Comment: @Criggie Not _the most_ ecologically responsible but a few batteries every 3-4 months is probably a pretty insignificant part of your overall footprint.

Comment: @nolawipetros Also, we can get tired of making sure that they're all on or off that we end up not using them, causing us not to benefit from the additional lights. Subjective safety can trick us not into using fewer lights. Some lights need cycling through their modes. Different modes are more suitable for different times of the day. A smarter option is using bike lights with front/rear combo so that fewer buttons need to be pressed. For example, a front+rear helmet light and a front+rear bike light.

Comment: @Han-Lin nah - things on helmets can cause them to not perform as required.  Front/back lights tend to be okay in one direction and poor in the other, cos the rider has to be somewhere.  You probably want an integrated light system with one button for multiple lights, hard-wired to the bike.

Comment: Just like what automobiles have!

Comment: @Criggie Actually an option already exists. It's dynamo lighting which means you don't even have to charge it at all. The small amount of drag and the reliability is likely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a light that uses the traditional  hard-plastic, circular seat-post clamp:

[image]

you want to find a light that uses an elastic (rubber/silicone) band that can stretch around your elliptical seat post:

[image]

(latter image from http://triedonline.com/cateye-rapid-x-rear-light-review/)

These are becoming much more popular because of their flexibility in attaching to all sorts of objects (backpacks, helmets, trailers, etc.). The longish LED strip also has a wider horizontal and vertical viewing angle than the single 5mm LED found in traditional lights so it doesn't matter if it is tilted down slightly.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a bag under your seat, you can put a light on that. There are also small LED lights that work well on helmets.